# How to get the uploaded filename from upload.php page Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, variables, upload, controller

I have Upload.php page as follows=>

```
<?php

   class Upload extends CI_Controller {

      public function __construct() { 
         parent::__construct(); 
         $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url')); 
      }

      public function index() { 
         $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' )); 
      } 

      public function do_upload() { 
         $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pgn'; 
         $config['max_size']      = 0; 
         //$config['max_width']     = 1024; 
         //$config['max_height']    = 768; 
          $config['detect_mime']    = TRUE;
         $this->load->library('upload', $config);

         if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error); 
         }

         else { 
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data); 
         } 
      } 
   } 
?>
```

and the Hesaplama.php controller as =>

```
    $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); //(line 51) Should return array of containing all of the data related to the file you uploaded.
    $file_name = $upload_data['file_name'];
    $file = fopen("<?php echo site_url('uploads/$file_name'); ?>", "r");

    while(! feof($file))
      {...
```

However I get the following error =>

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Hesaplama::$upload

Filename: controllers/Hesaplama.php

Line Number: 51

Backtrace:

File: D:\wamp\www\proje\application\controllers\Hesaplama.php
Line: 51
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\wamp\www\proje\application\controllers\Hesaplama.php
Line: 249
Function: pgn_oku

File: D:\wamp\www\proje\application\controllers\Welcome.php
Line: 28
Function: pozisyon_tutma

File: D:\wamp\www\proje\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

How can we remedy that and get the file name of the newly uploaded file?
I personally think that the program does not recognize the data in another page(controller).
Thank you...

Comment: Put `$config['max_size']      = 0;` for no limit.

Comment: Hello @Tpojka thank you. While searching through tutorials I too found that and was going to use it. Thank you

Comment: Be aware of values you are assigning and use it carefully. You put 23/24 digit number there, but check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) what is biggest int allowed. You have to consider files to be uploaded and since those are images/pictures, it can be set not more than 50 MB or 50000 in that value. Second thing is to see php.ini value because very often php_max_upload_size is set to 2 MB. That is just start without real solving your issue. Allowed types string shouldn't end with pipe `|`. It is unclear what url you type since you have 3 controllers in here.

Comment: Hello @Tpojka. I did some editing following your advice. In case you are wondering about the 'pgn' in respect to 'png' it is intentional and is not an image extension. I can upload these extensions with success. Thank you again..

Comment: @Otag there is no connectivity between `Hesaplama` and `Upload`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i can't comment yet, so i write it here. I think the library for

```
$this->upload->data();
```

wasn't loaded.

if you want to get only the filename, maybe you can try using session. 
in Upload controller:

```
$data = $this->upload->data();
$this->session->set_userdata('filename', $data['file_name']);
```

in Hesaplama :

```
$filename = 'uploads/'.$this->session->userdata('filename');
$file = fopen("<?php echo site_url('$filename'); ?>", "r");
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

to get the filename and extention file to save it in a db you can use tis

```
<?php

   class Upload extends CI_Controller {

      public function __construct() { 
         parent::__construct(); 
         $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url')); 
      }

      public function index() { 
         $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' )); 
      } 

      public function do_upload() { 
         $config['upload_path']     = './uploads/'; 
         $config['allowed_types']   = 'gif|jpg|png|pgn'; 
         $config['max_size']        = 0; 
         $config['detect_mime']    = TRUE;

         $this->load->library('upload', $config);

         if( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error); 
         }
         else { 
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

            /*
            Array
            (
                   [file_name]    => mypic.jpg
                   [file_type]    => image/jpeg
                   [file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
                   [full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
                   [raw_name]     => mypic
                   [orig_name]    => mypic.jpg
                   [client_name]  => mypic.jpg
                   [file_ext]     => .jpg
                   [file_size]    => 22.2
                   [is_image]     => 1
                   [image_width]  => 800
                   [image_height] => 600
                   [image_type]   => jpeg
                   [image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
            )
            */

            $this->model->save_img_info($upload_data['file_name']);

            $data = array('upload_data' => $upload_data ); 
            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data); 
         } 
      } 
   } 
?>
```